# Efficient keep only unique topics with full path (topic levels) in different columns

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

We have multilabel topics tagging model and we generate a dataframe full tagged for each level. That is, if we have a taxonomy of 3 levels and we have a topic tagged up to l3 (we can have just l1 l2 tagged for example) we will have 3 rows, 1 with l1 l2 l3 a second one with l1 l2 None and a third one with l1 None None. That is, for 1 tagged item with l3_a (from l1_a and l2_a), l1_b and l2_b (from l1_c) we have:

```
    1 l1_a l2_a l3_a
    2 l1_a l2_a None
    3 l1_a None None
    4 l1_b None None
    5 l1_c l2_b None
    6 l1_c None None
```

We would like to keep the row 1, the 4 and 5 rows also as they're "unique"
The rows 2 and 3 are identified by the row 1 (tagged up to l3) so we would like to drop them.

The row 4 is just tagged for l1_b (so we keep it). The row 5 was just tagged to l1_c and l2_b (so keep it also).

The solution that I found was:

```py
for i in range(n_levels, 0, -1):
    with_level = wide_topics[(wide_topics.iloc[:, :i].notnull()).all(axis=1)]
    if to_keep.empty:
        to_keep = with_level
    else:
        # Drop duplicates considering just these levels
        to_keep_this_level = (
            pd.concat([to_keep.reset_index(), with_level.reset_index()])
            .drop_duplicates(subset=with_level.columns[:i], keep=False)
            .set_index("index")
        )
        # Finally, add the indexes to to_keep and drop duplicates (added 2 times from with_level)
        to_keep = (
            pd.concat([to_keep_this_level, to_keep])
            .reset_index()
            .drop_duplicates(keep="first")
            .set_index("index")
        )
```

That is, First I keep the unique values that have all the levels and save it as "to_keep". Then, for each level below I concatenate the unique values that have all of these levels and drop the ones that we have already (by dropping duplicates up to this level) and finally I add these new unique values to the "to_keep" variable.
It does solve the problem but I required a for loop and a not-so-elegant solution.
I want to have a solution full-pandas but couldn't find it, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the values are sorted the way you showed, [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and identify the duplicates with [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = ~df.ffill().duplicated(subset=df.columns[1:])

out = df[m]
```

If the columns are not sorted, first [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
cols = list(df.columns[1:])
m = ~df.sort_values(by=cols)[cols].ffill().duplicated()

out = df[m]
```

Output:

```
   0     1     2     3
0  1  l1_a  l2_a  l3_a
3  4  l1_b   NaN   NaN
4  5  l1_c  l2_b   NaN
```

Intermediates:

```
   0     1     2     3 1_ffill 2_ffill 3_ffill      m
0  1  l1_a  l2_a  l3_a    l1_a    l2_a    l3_a   True
1  2  l1_a  l2_a   NaN    l1_a    l2_a    l3_a  False
2  3  l1_a   NaN   NaN    l1_a    l2_a    l3_a  False
3  4  l1_b   NaN   NaN    l1_b    l2_a    l3_a   True
4  5  l1_c  l2_b   NaN    l1_c    l2_b    l3_a   True
5  6  l1_c   NaN   NaN    l1_c    l2_b    l3_a  False
```

Comment: Great answer! Super smart use of ffill(). Just a small correction, duplicated() will get the duplicate by default all but the first occurence (keep='first') so we have the exact opposite of the m map. So using the same strategy but out = df[~m] gives the expected output :)

Comment: @GiovaniMerlin Yes, I forgot the `~` in the second code ;)